# how do I zip multiple files using GZipStream in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csv, gzip, filestream

I have created multiple csv files using datatable and want to zip all those file into one single zip file.
Which is i'm doing all at dynamically.

I tried following code

```
List<string> filestream = GenerateCSVfiles(dataSets);

//Generate CSV files
public List<string> GenerateCSVfiles(List<DataSet> dataSets)
{
    List<string> filestream = new List<string>();
    StringBuilder result = null;

    foreach (DataSet dataSet in dataSets)
    {
        result = new StringBuilder();

        System.Data.DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables[0];

        foreach (DataColumn colm in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            result.Append(colm.ColumnName+",");
        }

        result.Append("\n");

        //create csv file
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                result.Append(row[i].ToString());
                result.Append(i == dataTable.Columns.Count - 1 ? "\n" : ",");
            }    
        }

        filestream.Add(result.ToString());   
    }

    return filestream;
}
```

Now in `List<filestream>` I have all 2 file data want to create 2 different `.csv` files and create  one `temp.gz` file dynamically How can I do this ?

On `ActionResult` method I tried following code to generate .zip file but it is corrupted

```
return File(CompressStringToFile("temp.gz", filestream), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip, "temp.gz");
```

// zip file generation code

```
public byte[] CompressStringToFile(string fileName, List<string> filestream)
{   
    MemoryStream  f2 = new MemoryStream();
    FileStream fs = new FileStream();
    GZipStream gz = new GZipStream(f2, CompressionMode.Compress, false);

    foreach (string oStr in filestream)
    {
        byte[] b = GetBytes(oStr);
        gz.Write(b, 0, b.Length);                    
    }

    return f2.ToArray();
}
```

> Correct me to generate .zip file. (with inside 2 .csv files)

Comment: The code you've posted has absolutely nothing to do with your question. Calling a List<String> filestream isn't a good idea. You have no files, your method GenerateCSVfiles doesn't! Hard to figure out how to help you...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson updated my full code please check

Comment: You mention `ActionResult`.  Can you confirm you are using MVC? If so, you should add it to the tags.
What are you expected to return in the ActionResult method.  You want the user to download the zip file?

Comment: GZipStream does not support creating an archive that contains multiple compressed files.  You need a library that supports .gz or .zip archives.  Lots of them around, finally added to .NET 4.5 as well with the ZipFile class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with a `GZipStream`. You'll need a 3rd party library. Probably the best one out there is [SharpZipLib](http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/). I've used this on projects in the past, and it's very easy to use. Plus it's been around for a while so should be pretty stable and bug-free.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install the NuGet package **DotNetZip**.

This will work for you:

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile()
    {
        string string1 = "value1, value2, value3, value4";
        string string2 = "value10, value20, value30, value40";


        List<String> files =  new List<String>();
        files.Add(string1);
        files.Add(string2);

        byte[] buffer = CompressStringToFile("myfile.zip", files);

        return File(buffer, "application/zip");
    }


private byte[] CompressStringToFile(string fileName, List<string> content)
    {
        byte[] result = null;
        int count = 0;

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var s = new ZipOutputStream(ms))
            {
                foreach (string str in content)
                {
                    s.PutNextEntry(String.Format("entry{0}.txt", count++));
                    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
                    s.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
            }

            result = ms.ToArray();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: According to the reviews of DotNetZip it has some really bad bugs. Personally I do not dare using it because of these reviews.