# Memory usage when creating and downloading zip archive as HttpContent

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api GET method that returns a zip file for downloading. Here's the code that creates the zip archive:

```
var resultStream = new MemoryStream();    
using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(resultStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, leaveOpen: true))
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(file.Path, file.Name, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
    }
}
```

And here's how the response gets populated:

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(resultStream.ToArray());
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "export_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss") + ".zip";
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.Size = resultStream.Length;
response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = resultStream.Length;
```

The code above works just fine, the problem is it consumes a lot of memory on the server, depending of course on the file sizes. I've tried changing the result to `StreamContent`, however this didn't work as the response only returned headers and eventually timed out.

So here are my questions:

1. Is there a way to avoid loading all files in memory and instead send the zip file as it gets created?
2. Is using StreamContent better to use in this scenario and if yes, what do I need to change to make it work?
3. How is buffering affecting memory consumption in each case? I've tried disabling buffering by implementing a custom `IHostBufferPolicySelector` as suggested [in this article](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/), but it doesn't appear to have any effect.
4. The api action currently can be called by navigating a link, using HttpClient or by AJAX request, so any solution has to support all scenarios.

Comment: Try using GZipStream and PushStreamContent

Comment: How many requests do you get on your server?

Comment: You won't be able to set the content-length though, so will need enable chunk encoding.

Comment: @AliHasan 2-3 concurrent requests max. It's an internal application, so using ByteArrayContent is still an option.

Comment: Do you have any objects that you did not disposed?

Comment: and what's the size of the zip files?

Comment: They are dynamically constructed based on URL input. The max size is configurable, currently no more than 30 files/1 GB (uncompressed size) are allowed

Comment: Thanks @DarrelMiller, unfortunately GZipStream is not an option when adding multiple files to a zip file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571773/how-do-i-zip-multiple-files-using-gzipstream-in-c-sharp

Comment: I did not know that.  But PushStreamContent should still be useful for minimizing memory usage.

Comment: No worries, neither did I. Alex's answer looks promising and it's using PushStreamContent, so I'll give it a try.

Comment: @elolos can you please show u are returning the zip file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapted from the [`Kudu`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/master/Kudu.Services/Infrastructure/ZipStreamContent.cs) project, a method that uses `PushStreamContent` in combination with a specific `DelegatingStream` wrapper to stream a zip archive:

```
public static class ZipStreamContent
{
    public static PushStreamContent Create(string fileName, Action<ZipArchive> onZip)
    {
        var content = new PushStreamContent((outputStream, httpContent, transportContext) =>
        {
            using (var zip = new ZipArchive(new StreamWrapper(outputStream), ZipArchiveMode.Create, leaveOpen: false))
            {
                onZip(zip);
            }
        });
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");
        content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
        return content;        
    }

    // this wraps the read-only HttpResponseStream to support ZipArchive Position getter.
    public class StreamWrapper : DelegatingStream
    {
        private long _position = 0;

        public StreamWrapper(Stream stream)
            : base(stream)
        {
        }

        public override long Position
        {
            get { return _position; }
            set { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
        }

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            _position += count;
            base.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        }

        public override IAsyncResult BeginWrite(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
        {
            _position += count;
            return base.BeginWrite(buffer, offset, count, callback, state);
        }
    }
}
```

Which for your case you could use like:

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
var response.Content = ZipStreamContent.Create(
    "export_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss") + ".zip",
    zipArchive => {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(file.Path, file.Name, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
        }        
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Alex, what is a DelegatingStream and how can I use it?

Comment: Err, you may need to massage this a bit: an `internal` abstract class in the ASP.NET stack (namespace `System.Net.Http`), you can find its source [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Net.Http/System/Net/Http/DelegatingStream.cs)

Comment: Just tried it and it seems that `PushStreamContent` is a great solution, memory usage is now very low. 

However, I've encountered a problem whenever there is an exception within the zip method, the response fails but the response status is still 200, which unfortunately breaks any AJAX calls.

Comment: @elolos I am not sure. I don't think you can set the response code after the fact. What if you omit the status code in the constructor and just do `var response = new HttpResponseMessage()`

Comment: It seems that exceptions are not sent to the client because they happen way after the client has received a 200 OK response. So I'm afraid that even though this is a great solution from a memory perspective, it is not as useful in the context my code has to be used.

Comment: @elolos It seems that you could solve this if you do some handshaking with your client, e.g. add a correlation id (guid) to the response header, and have your client check for failures with a new request using this correlation id, once the stream completes. It is an ugly non-stateless solution though. Or make the response content multipart and attach a footer to the response.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, both equally interesting solutions. Unfortunately they cannot work in the context of the existing code, for example javascript is expecting an error status code in order to display errors.  

I think I'll stick with the current implementation, as the increased memory consumption is a small price to pay given the low number of requests. But I would definitely consider your solution under most circumstances.