# How to Zip a MemoryStream of an image

Tags: c#, arrays, image, zip, memorystream

I have byte array of an image, I want to create Zip file from it.

I can save the byte array in jpg file successfully, But when I create zip file from it, the image of the zip file (the image that is into the zip file) was damaged and I Can't open it!
(when I try to open the image, Winrar display error message bellow:
    D:\sample.zip: The archive is either in unknown format or damaged
)

Note: My image is in memory and I don't want to create physically image file.

Here is my codes:

```
private void Zip(byte[] imageBytes)
{
    string filePath = string.Empty;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (var zip = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        var entry = zip.CreateEntry("sample.jpg", CompressionLevel.Optimal);

        using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
        using (var fileToCompressStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
        {
            fileToCompressStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
        }

        using (var fs = new FileStream(baseFilePath + "sample.zip", FileMode.Create))
        {
            ms.Position = 0;
            ms.WriteTo(fs);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also create new Bitmap instance from imageBytes (parameter) and save it into entryStream, But same issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just do:

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Text;

private void Zip (byte[] imageBytes) {

 string fileName = baseFilePath + "sample.zip";
 using (FileStream f2 = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create)){
        using (GZipStream gz = new GZipStream(f2, CompressionMode.Compress, false))
        {
            gz.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: It works fine. thanks. how can I set name of image file ? (it save with same name of zip file without any extension)

Comment: I think, GZip is not good for my situation because I need to put multi image in a zip file eventually and as far as I know, GZipStream is good for zip just one file. Am I right ?

Comment: You are correct read here for how to do multiple files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571773/how-do-i-zip-multiple-files-using-gzipstream-in-c-sharp

Comment: **SharpZipLib** is very useful library. (https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpZipLib/)